# Text size is not getting changed for different screen layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-studio, text-size

I am trying to make my app multi screen supportable for that I have created different layout folders like `layout-large` , `layout-small` ,`layout-xlarge` , `layout-sw320dp` , `layout-sw480dp` , I have set text size in sp in each folder and i have mentioned different text sizes for every layout folder but text is not getting changed.

Here is  my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_pager"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstscreen_call_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/firstscreen_layout_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:background="@color/call_list_1"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/call_list_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Call List"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cm_phone_icon"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@color/call_list_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"

            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_client_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="350" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_client_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Clients 99 Priority" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gray_bg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_service_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="3250" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_service_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Servicing Contacts" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_assigned_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="250" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_assigned_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Assigned Contacts" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_custom_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call_list_custom_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Custom List" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstscreen_client_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/firstscreen_layout_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:background="@color/client_note_1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/client_note_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Client Note"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cm_note_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@color/client_note_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_notes_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="10" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_notes_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Notes Logged Today" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_meeting_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_meeting_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Meetings Schedule" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_phone_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_phone_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Phone Calls" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_email_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/client_note_email_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Email(s) Sent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstscreen_to_do_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/firstscreen_layout_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:background="@color/to_do_list_1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/todolist_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="To-Do List"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cm_todo_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@color/to_do_list_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_open_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="20" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_open_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Open Task" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_expire_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_expire_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Expiring Today" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_direct_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="25" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_direct_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Directed Calls" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gray_bg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_action_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/todolist_action_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Actions Pending" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstscreen_road_show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/firstscreen_layout_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:background="@color/roadshow_1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roadshow_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Roadshow"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cm_roadshow_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@color/roadshow_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_meeting_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="10" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_meeting_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Meetings Schedule" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_ongoing_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_ongoing_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ongoing Roadshow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_future_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_future_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Future Roadshow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_mtoday_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roadshow_mtoday_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Meetings Today" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On what devices have you tested? What are their resolutions?

Comment: @EricB. am testing on moto g3

Comment: all over you app or for any one file?

Comment: How can you know that this is not working by testing in only one device?

Comment: @sree only for one file

Comment: post that file please

Comment: @Jas after testing it on device that its working or not only than i'l move on other device

Comment: You won't be be able to notice the difference in just one device, unless you specify another layout for landscape. You can check if the layout for landscape is shown, you can be sure, layout for other screens will be shown too.

Comment: @Sree i have added my xml code in question please check

Comment: all the text are not getting changed is it ?

Comment: Try to set text size in dp as sp depends on user font size settings so u are facing this problem due to device font size settings

Comment: try with different textSizes

Comment: i just implemented you xml, i cant find any issue and unfortunately i dot have a moto g3 , hope you know which layout is taking for moto g3 , so try to edit that file accordingly  and test in other device

Comment: @Sree yeah right sree all the text are not getting changed

Comment: @kapilrajput i have tried both sp as well as dp but none of them is working

Comment: @Sree in my phone text with numeric number is not coming proper on screen

Comment: can you tell me which layout( layout-large , layout-small ,layout-xlarge , layout-sw320dp , layout-sw480dp) is called on your device

Comment: Just set tag on all layouts to check which screen layout is called for your device

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me.. issue ressolved

Answer (score 0):

For   best practice for text size we need to simply define the text size is sp .

and we should set text as below

textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textSize));